# regex findall in beautifulsoup -python 3

Tags: regex, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, findall

I need to get the name and value and context ref for all the fields under the tag `ix:nonfraction` which looks like this:

`<ix:nonfraction name="uk-gaap:TangibleFixedAssets" contextref="FY1.END" unitref="GBP" xmlns:uk-gaap="http://www.xbrl.org/uk/gaap/core/2009-09-01" decimals="0" format="ixt:numcommadot">238,011</ix:nonfraction>`.

with the output needed as :

```
TangibleFixedAssets, FY1.end, 238,011
```

the string that the regex will have to search through contains many of these tags so would there be a way of keeping all the 3 outputs concatenated (or within the same index of the list)?

Comment: Try this    **\<ix:nonfraction.*(?:name\=\"[\w\-]+\:([\w]+)\")\s*(?:contextref\=\"([\w\.]+)\").*\>([\w\,]+)\<\/ix:nonfraction\>**.  Use **g** global modifer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bs4
html = '''<ix:nonfraction name="uk-gaap:TangibleFixedAssets" contextref="FY1.END" unitref="GBP" xmlns:uk-gaap="http://www.xbrl.org/uk/gaap/core/2009-09-01" decimals="0" format="ixt:numcommadot">238,011</ix:nonfraction>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

ixs = soup.find_all('ix:nonfraction')
for ix in ixs:
    name = ix['name'].split(':')[-1]
    contextref = ix['contextref']
    text = ix.text
    output = [name, contextref, text]
    print(output)
```

out:

```
['TangibleFixedAssets', 'FY1.END', '238,011']
```